# Java jdbc float and postgres type mapping

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, types

what is the mapping between Float java type and postgresql type? I've try with numeric but i don't know in advance how big could be the precision

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use general `numeric` without precision and scale.

Or use `real` for 4 byte float and `double` for 8 byte float.

Details on postgres Numeric Types [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)